# How to copy Column 1 data from dataGrid1 to dataGrid2? C# WinForms - UserControl Form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I'm using WinForms and I have created a User Control called "Phases.cs". In the User Control I have used Tab Control. In Tab1 I have a Data Grid, 'dataGridType' that has 6 columns. In Tab2 I have a Data Grid, 'dataGridTimings'. I want the app to work so that when a user enters values into column 1 of 'dataGridType', the values are copied to 'dataGridTimigns' column 1.

I can't get the data to be copied across.

I also want the values of column 3 of dataGridType to be copied to column 2 of dataGridTimings, but I haven't tried that yet.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TOPAS2500
{
    public partial class Phases : UserControl
    {
        public Phases()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridType_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the value of the cell that was just edited.
            string value = dataGridType.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            // Get the `dataGridViewTimings` control.
            DataGridView dataGridTimings = (DataGridView)this.Controls["dataGridTimings"];

            // Set the value of the corresponding cell in `dataGridTimings`.
            dataGridTimings.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = value;
        }
    }
}`
```

I have also made sure that Enabled and Visible are set to true in the properties of both grids.

**Phase data entry**:

[image: Phase data entry]

**Column I want the data to be moved to**:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the correct `DataGridView` object is referenced when you type `this.Controls["dataGridTimings"];`? Can't you just simply reach the grid view by calling `this.dataGridTimings`. Assuming that grid view is created correctly in your Phases `UserControl`.